How do I eliminate rows from an excel table when the value of the second column is 0?



Ingredients
Amount




Ingredient 1
Amount 1


Ingredient 2
Amount 2


Ingredient 3
Amount 3



If ingredient 1 is 2 and ingredient 2 is also 2, but ingredient 3 is 0, I want the new table to read:



Ingredients
Amount




Ingredient 1
2


Ingredient 2
2



I've read through and attempted a few formulas, but I'm new to this and couldn't get anything to stick.

Use FILTER() function --> =FILTER(A2:B4,B2:B3>0)
